# Can't figure out why the rest of my header will not show

Tags: javascript, html, header, appendchild

```
    <head>
```

function that is called when the page loads

```
    <body onload="myOnload()">
```

header *div* with custom graphic

```
    <div id="header">
    <img src="resumeheader.png" alt="Header" style="width:750px;height:100px;">
    <h2>Pay Calculator</h2>
    <h3></h3>

    <script>
```

this function shows the hour

```
    function myOnload(){
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getHours();
        document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = n;
```

*if...else if... else statement* for time for greeting

```
    if (new Date().getHours() < 12) {
    document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "Enjoy the rest of your morning!";
    } else if (new Date().getHours() < 17) {
    document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "Enjoy the afternoon!";
    } else  (new Date().getHours() > 17) 
    document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "Have a good evening!";
```

these variables should make it possible for the code to show in my *header*

```
    var firstVariable = document.createElement("H3"); 
    var secondVariable = document.createTextNode(n);
    firstVariable.appendChild(secondVariable);
    document.body.appendChild(firstVariable); 
    }


    </script>
```

end javascript

```
    </div>
    </body>
    </head>
```

Comment: What is the question? Oh, and the `<body>` goes *after* the `<head>`, not inside it.

Comment: well that was an honest mistake, but only the appendchild shows, instead of the that with the rest of the header

Comment: The `<head>` element is *not* for a page header or anything like that. It's for document metadata, CSS and script imports, etc. The `<header>` tag *is* for displayed headers.

Comment: that's not the issue, the appendchild is taking place of everything on the header div, i need what is within the appendchild and the header to be displayed together

Comment: I repeat: the `<head>` element is **not for the page header**. Its contents are **hidden**. *edit* Oh wait, OK OK I see what you mean. (You still need to move the `<body>` out of the `<head>` though if you haven't already.)

Comment: that does not fix the problem, i said this before

Comment: Note that every time you set `.innerHTML` on the "header" element, you overwrite its complete contents.

Comment: i did that, then i run the webpage and it still only shows the appendchild in the header div. i am at a loss for what to do

Comment: if i remove the .innerHTML then the greeting will not show

Comment: It's not clear what you want. [Here is a jsfiddle version of your code.](https://jsfiddle.net/1x5rh8s9/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to take care of your code like this line `} else  (new Date().getHours() > 17)`

try the following code:

```html
<html>
 
  
<head>



</head>
  
  <body onload="myOnload()">
<div id="header"></div>
    <div id=img><img src="resumeheader.png" alt="Header" style="width:750px;height:100px;"></div><div id=h2>
    <h2>Pay Calculator</h2>
    <h3></h3></div>



<script>
function myOnload(){
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getHours();
        document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = n;

  if (n < 12) {
    document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "Enjoy the rest of your morning!";
    } else if (n < 17 && n > 12) {
    document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "Enjoy the afternoon!";
    } else {
    document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "Have a good evening!";
    }
    var firstVariable = document.createElement("H3"); 
    var secondVariable = document.createTextNode(n);
    firstVariable.appendChild(secondVariable);
    document.body.appendChild(firstVariable); 
    }

  </script>
```

Comment: this worked thank you, but the custom graphic and <h2> header are below the div, do you know how i could place them both in the same div?

Comment: make div container for them

Comment: how would i  do that?

Comment: <div id=container><div id=header></div><img src="resumeheader.png" alt="Header" style="width:750px;height:100px;">
    <h2>Pay Calculator</h2> </div> and make suitable css

Comment: i have suitable css for that div but it doesn't seem like what you gave me worked because nothing changed

Comment: make sure you changed the id correct , the new div id is container but this is not big issue you can adjusted , i am sure

Comment: trying to adjust but no change, only the greeting is in the div and then the graphic and heading are outside and below it

Comment: #header {
    background-color:Maroon;
    color:black;
    text-align:center;
 padding:5px; this is the basic css i have for the div now

Comment: <style> #img{float:left} #h2{float:right}</style> try this style with new change

Comment: if all greeting,graphic and he in same line you must separate each one in div then in style sheet you can distribute the width like 40% for img , 30% for greeting ,30% h2

Comment: i have an external style sheet, so how would i go about this

Comment: even after your updated edit, it looks the same as in the photo that i uploaded, this issue is quite perplexing and i appreciate your help